# Angular $cookieStore not retaining updated cookie on refresh

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I'm having issues with $cookieStore retaining a cookie value after updating it.  Here are two methods of a UserService that deals with the cookie:

```
var getCurrentUser = function () {
    return $cookieStore.get('currentUser');
};

var updateCurrentUser = function () {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + 'api/session').then(function (response) {
        $cookieStore.put('currentUser', response.data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('currentUser', response.data);
    }, function (response) {
        $cookieStore.remove('currentUser');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('currentUser', null);
    });
};
```

Throughout my app, after an action is executed that would affect the current user's meta data, I call `UserService.updateCurrentUser()` which retrieves the latest user data from the server and updates that cookie.  Then, in places that display the user data, I have the following code that will update the user model in that particular controller:

```
$scope.$on('currentUser', function (event, data) {
    $scope.user = data;
});
```

As I step through the code, everything appears to be working correctly.  After the `$cookieStore.put('currentUser', response.data);`  line runs, the updated value can be confirmed by checking `$cookieStore.get('currentUser')`.  When I check the actual cookie using a browser tool, however, the cookie value is not updated.  I'm not sure if the browser tool requires a refresh to show the new data.  But when I refresh the page, the updated cookie value is also no where to be seen.  What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the documentation for put(...) - there is a 3rd argument with additional options including when the cookie should expire. Otherwise it will expire on refresh. Also the service is now called `$cookies`, I'm not sure which version of angular you're using, but I assume it's similar enough to work from the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: @DavidSpence: Thanks!  I had to replace angular 1.3.15 with 1.4.0 to get the cookie functionality described in that document.  I can set expires now, although the current issue is reducing the cookie size to under 4kb...

Comment: Sweet! Adding answer for sweet, sweet internet points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the documentation adding a cookie using `$cookie` service:

```
put(key, value, [options]);
```

The third argument allows additional options:

- path (string)
- domain (string)
- expires (date)
- secure (boolean)

You should set "expires" to define when the cookie should expire, otherwise the cookie will expire when you refresh or leave the site.

```
$cookies.put("id", 1, {
    expires: new Date(2016, 1, 1)
});
```

Also the service is now called `$cookies`. Since Angular 1.4 you can now set expiry. Until then it wasn't possible.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies